# Not Returning To AJAX Success From C# Controller Action

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Not Returning To AJAX Success From C# Controller Action
I Have Tried Many Options Available But Its Still Not Returning Data To AJAX Success What Could Be The Reason ?
I Want To Return List `Listemr_t_Immunization` From Action Of Controller To My Success data Of The AJAX Call How Should I Do That

Please See The Following Code Thank You

**AJAX Request**

```
$.ajax(
             {
                 url: '@Url.Action("getmedi", "Immunization")',
                 type: 'Post',
                 async: false,
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: JSON.stringify({ "patient2": patient2}),
                 success: function (data) {
                     debugger
                     $(data).each(function(index, element){
                         $('#first > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                         $('#first > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(1)').append('<input id='+element.ImmunizationId+' value='+element.VaccineName+'>');
                         $('#first > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(2)').append('<input id='+element.Immunization_Id+' value='+element.DateGiven+'>');
                         $('#first > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(3)').append('<input id='+element.Immunization_Id+' value='+element.Route+'>');



                     })
                     $("input[name='VaccineName']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                     $("input[name='DateGiven']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                     $("input[name='Route']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                 },
                 error: function (textStatus, errorThrown)
                 {
                     debugger
                 }

             });
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getmedi(int patient2)
        {
            if (patient2.ToString() != "")
            {
                string roster = objOrgCont.getmedi(patient2);

                JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                emr_t_Immunization erx = (emr_t_Immunization)ser.Deserialize(roster, typeof(emr_t_Immunization));

                List<emr_t_Immunization> Listemr_t_Immunization = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(Allemr_t_Immunization => Allemr_t_Immunization.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList();

                ///List<emr_t_Medical_History> Listemr_t_Medical_History2 = (from Allemr_t_Medical_History in db.emr_t_Medical_History where Allemr_t_Medical_History.Mr_No == Mr_No select Allemr_t_Medical_History).ToList();

                if (erx != null)
                {
                    //return Json(new { success = true, for_Date = erx.Med_Date, for_Name = erx.Name, for_Active = erx.Active, for_Resolved = erx.Resolved, for_Comments=erx.Comments });
                    return Json(new { Listemr_t_Immunization, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet });
                }

            }

            return Json(new { success = false });

        }
```

I Have Also Tried To Stringify It Before Returning And It Shows Following Error

I Have Used 
`return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Listemr_t_Immunization);`

Now It Is Giving Me Error

> Self referencing loop detected with type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.as_t_appointment_305685F58BEE75BAC95975F9457412A0DE58BB59D3EDBD1155C7DB5E21A7BA66'.
>   Path
>   '[0].erx_t_patient.as_t_appointment[0].erx_t_city.as_t_appointment'

Comment: you mean to say everytime it's coming in error callback ??

Comment: I Want To Return List `Listemr_t_Immunization`

Comment: return Json(new { Listemr_t_Immunization, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet }); Try that

Comment: What is your actual question now? Update your original post to make more sense with what you want done, and I will try and help you

Comment: Okay I Will Update But I Want To Return List `Listemr_t_Immunization` To My Success `data` Of The AJAX Call How Should I Do That

Comment: What does data contain when you debug it in Javascript?  Do you get any console errors with your jquery code?

Comment: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:14333/Immunization/getmedi 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Okay, have you debugged your C# function?  Http error 500 usually means something went wrong on the server side. I have a feeling your code crashes, and therefore it does not reach any of your return statements. Try putting try {} catch {} blocks, and see if you can capture the exception.  Your code is likely to fail on objOrgCont.getmedi(patient2), or the Deserialize(roster, typeof(emr_t_Immunization)) functions

Comment: No There Exception I Have Checked The Result Is Returning Fine 
Now It Goes To Success Function But There I Dont Not Have Any Data How Can I Return `Listemr_t_Immunization`

Comment: `return Json(new { success = false, Listemr_t_Immunization }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
I Also Tried This But Yes It Goes To Succes But There Is not List All I Can See In Data Is `data= Object{success=false}`

Comment: I Have Used 
`return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Listemr_t_Immunization);`
Now It Is Giving Me Error
`Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.as_t_appointment_305685F58BEE75BAC95975F9457412A0DE58BB59D3EDBD1155C7DB5E21A7BA66'. Path '[0].erx_t_patient.as_t_appointment[0].erx_t_city.as_t_appointment'`

Answer (score 0):

Just from a quick glance, it looks like you could move your failure returns into else statements to protect them from being fired unless one of your conditions fail, rather than just floating outside on its own.

Is the issue that your call back fails every time? If so that could be the reason.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult getmedi(int patient2)
    {
        if (patient2.ToString() != "")
        {
            string roster = objOrgCont.getmedi(patient2);

            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            emr_t_Immunization erx = (emr_t_Immunization)ser.Deserialize(roster, typeof(emr_t_Immunization));

            List<emr_t_Immunization> Listemr_t_Immunization = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(Allemr_t_Immunization => Allemr_t_Immunization.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList();

            ///List<emr_t_Medical_History> Listemr_t_Medical_History2 = (from Allemr_t_Medical_History in db.emr_t_Medical_History where Allemr_t_Medical_History.Mr_No == Mr_No select Allemr_t_Medical_History).ToList();

            if (erx != null)
            {
                //return Json(new { success = true, for_Date = erx.Med_Date, for_Name = erx.Name, for_Active = erx.Active, for_Resolved = erx.Resolved, for_Comments=erx.Comments });
                return Json(new { Listemr_t_Immunization, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet });
            } else 
            {
               return Json(new { success = false });
            }
        } else

        {
          return Json(new { success = false });
        }

    }
```

Also on a side note, a better way to deal with success and failure of API-ish stuff is to use the HTTP error codes.

```
 Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
 return Json(new { results });
```

EDIT

To send a list back in your request.

This line here will need to change:

```
List<emr_t_Immunization> Listemr_t_Immunization = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(Allemr_t_Immunization => Allemr_t_Immunization.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList();
```

I am guessing that db is your context object and if so replace that line with:

```
var results = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(Allemr_t_Immunization => Allemr_t_Immunization.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList()
```

I am not 100% sure what erx is, but if you are checking that you have results then change that to.

```
  if (results.Any())
    {
     Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Created;
     return Json(new { results });
    } else 
    {
      Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
      return Json("Failed");
    }
```

So all up your code will read:

```
 [HttpPost]
     public JsonResult getmedi(int patient2)
      {
          if (patient2.ToString() != "")
          {
            string roster = objOrgCont.getmedi(patient2);
            JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            emr_t_Immunization erx =(emr_t_Immunization)ser.Deserialize(roster, typeof(emr_t_Immunization));
            var results = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(Allemr_t_Immunization     => Allemr_t_Immunization.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList()
            /// You can make that query easier to read by having
            /// var results = db.emr_t_Immunization.Where(a => a.Patient_Id == patient2).ToList()
        if (results.Any())
         {
          Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Created;
          return Json(new { results });
         } else 
         {
           Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
           return Json("Failed");
         }
      } else
      {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("Failed");
      }

    }
```

Comment: I Want To Return List Listemr_t_Immunization To My Success data Of The AJAX Call How Should I Do That